# Is it possible to configure Apache2 to load PHP with different modules per vhost?

Tags: php, apache2

I have a server with Apache2, that used to handle my target site and phpmyadmin for site's DB. Both phpmyadmin and site are using PHP 7.4. I need xDebug to debug my site, but it is loaded for phpmyadmin too, so phpmyadmin slows down and tries to load connect to my IDE. Can I turn off xDebug for phpmyadmin and keep it on for another virtual host?